# Possibility of passing MyObject to bean routing using Apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am consuming messages from Apache kafka using apache camel JAVA DSLs.
I am writing an object by converting it to `byte[]` on kafka. when I consume it I receive a message back with `byte[]`. I deserialize it and get an object.

I checks it if it is an object of `MyObject` then need to pass it to bean using java DSL `.to()`. My code is as below:

```
public class KafkaRouter extends RouteBuilder {
    
    private MessageBean msgBean;
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        from("{{kafka.cons.uri}}").process(new Processor() {
            
            
            
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                Object obj = SerializationUtils.deserialize(exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class));                //TODO cast to specific class as returned after deserialization.
                
                if(obj !=null && obj instanceof MessageBean){
                    
                    msgBean = (MessageBean)obj;
                    
                }
                else {
                    
                    throw new PTFException("Invalid Message read in Kafka Consumer");
                }
                
            }
            
            
        }).bean(PTFTransformerService.class,"callTransformerService(msgBean)"); ;
    }
```

Now issue is I just want `MyObject` in corresponding called method and I do not want to use `TypeConvertors`. I do not want to get Exchange/body in method I will process my stream in process and throw exception if read invalid messages and do not forward it to the bean.

My method on the other end will be:

```
private void callTransformerService(MessageBean msgObj){
    // Got my object here ;-)   
        
    }
```

Comment: You need to replace the old body with msgBean in your process method above, eg exchange.getIn().setBody(msgBean);

Comment: Thanks. this is what I did at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `@Body` before function argument `MessageBean msgObj`:

```
import org.apache.camel.Body;

private void callTransformerService(@Body MessageBean msgObj){

}
```

Comment: and how you write this bit of code "bean(PTFTransformerService.class,"callTransformerService(msgBean)"); " BTW changing to what you said did not work.

Comment: try without  brackets, only method name: bean(PTFTransformerService.class,"callTransformerService"); 
or bean(new PTFTransformerService(),"callTransformerService");

Comment: that does not work either. if I set exchange body to an Object that works but I do not want that as said. just need to pass object to a method.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand your code previously. I think that your way to do this can't work, because you can only pass to bean method somethink from your exchange, so you must set body or header (if you don't want to change body), and that header pass to your method using simple language:
exchange.getIn().setHeader("headerName",msgBean);
.bean(PTFTransformerService.class,"callTransformerService(${header.headerName})")
or
exchange.getIn().setBody(msgBean);
.bean(PTFTransformerService.class,"callTransformerService")

Answer (score 1):

You may need to write a custom fallback type converter that can convert from kafka byte[] to your POJOs

- http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html

Then you can just define the pojo type in the bean and Camel will use the fallback type converter to try to convert to the pojo type.

Comment: but this involves adding a TypeConverter file on some path and providing list of packages in META-INF file which I don't feel comfortable.. and why camel do not provide a way to simply pass an object to a bean method ?

Comment: Surely it does, just use java.lang.Object as the type. I suggest you study more about Camel, such as about bean component / bean parameter bindings. You can read the free chapter 4 of the CiA2 book or browse the Camel website docs - http://manning.com/ibsen2/

Comment: Thanks claus, I got your point. but if you see my code I wish to pass myObject that I created after reading Body from exchange. Now is it possible without using TypeConverters I can pass it like 'bean(PTFTransformerService.class,"callTransformerService(myObject)");' I know I can play with Body and set any type of Object and get on the other part as @Body.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Exchange Body in the Processor as follows below:

```
msgBean = (MessageBean)obj;
exchange.getIn().setBody(msgBean, MessageBean.class);
void callTransformerService(@Body MessageBean msgObj) {}
```